# Python: List inside function taking previous value

Tags: python, list, object

The list (array) inside a python function is taking value from previous instance of function call when the value is not passed as argument. For eg.

```
def abc(val, y=[]):
   y.append(val)
   return y
print(abc(3))  # Output: [3]
print(abc(4, [1,2]))  # Output : [1, 2, 4]
print(abc(10))  # Output: [3, 10]  # Expected value was [10]
```

Can anybody please explain why `y` holds value from previous call when it is not passed as argument?

Comment: ya, the question is almost same as the question in the link you provided above.

Comment: One of the default (pun intended) pitfalls. You can do it like so:  `def abc(val, y=None): y = y or []; y.append(val); return y` :)